# Copy files from folders and search specific directory for same folder names powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I need to copy files from one folder directory to a different folder directory, but the `tree` structure of directory 2 is not the same as directory 1. Here's an example:

```
Directory1
--folder1
----text1.pdf
----text2.pdf
--folder2
----text3.pdf
----text4.pdf


Directory2
--home1
----folder1
------text1.pdf
------text2.pdf
--home2
----folder2
------text3.pdf
------text4.pdf
```

The folders `"folder1"` and `"folder2"` will be in `Directory2`, but they may be in different folders.

Comment: ofc it's possible, but do you have something that links the source(e.g. folder1) to the destination (e.g. home1/folder1)? Ending number always equal? csv-records with "old" and "new" location? You should at least give it a try and provide a code sample of what you've tried as this sound more like "if this is possible, do it for me". :-)

Comment: The folder names would be the same in both locations, but the location of the 2nd directory could change daily. It may be in home1 or home5. I did try to start to write this, but I'm not very good at scripting, and ended up copying files all over the place. Not asking for someone to write it, just wanted to know if it's possible and where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
$dirs1 =
get-childitem c:\directory1 -recurse |
 where {$_.psiscontainer} |
 select -ExpandProperty fullname

$dirs2 =
get-childitem c:\directory2 -recurse |
 where {$_.psiscontainer} |
 select -ExpandProperty fullname

 $dir_ht = @{}

 foreach ($dir in $dirs1)
 {
  $root = $dir -replace '.+Directory1',''
  $dir_ht[$dir] = ($dirs2 -match $root)
}

$files =
get-childitem c:\directory1 -recurse |
 where {-not($_.psiscontainer)} |
 select -ExpandProperty fullname

foreach ($file in $files)
 {copy-item -Path $file -Destination $dir_ht[($file | Split-Path -Parent)]}
```

Comment: This one is taking the files and copying all the files from the $dirs1 directory folders and putting them in my windows user directory. I'm gonna see if I can play around with this. Thank you for pointing me in a direction.